# How to delete a single row from database using linq query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is my table ts_grp_perm_mapping

```
grp_permid     grp_id      perm_id
22              4           1
23              2           2
```

This is my code to delete row.
`usr_groupId` below is `grp_id` in above table.
`usr_doctypeids` below is `perm_id` in above table.

```
public int saveNewUser(int usr_groupId, int usr_doctypeids)
{
     ts_grp_perm_mapping tm = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Find(usr_groupId);
     db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Remove(tm);
     int rowiseffected=db.SaveChanges();
     return rowiseffected;
}
```

When I trace my `tm` shows null, and error pops up like values cannot be null. So where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please give actual definition of `ts_grp_perm_mapping`.

Comment: grp_id is primary key?

Comment: grp_id is forein key. grp_permid is primary. I am trying to delete based on grp_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If grp_id is Primary Key

```
 public int saveNewUser(int usr_groupId, int usr_doctypeids)
    {
         ts_grp_perm_mapping tm = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.SingleOrDefault(ts => ts.grp_id == usr_groupId);
         if(tm != null)
             {
         db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Remove(tm);
         int rowiseffected=db.SaveChanges();
         return rowiseffected;
    }
    else
    {
    return 0;
    }
    }
```

If grp_id is not a primary key

```
public int saveNewUser(int usr_groupId, int usr_doctypeids)
        {
             ts_grp_perm_mapping tm = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.FirstOrDefault(ts => ts.grp_id == usr_groupId);
             if(tm != null)
                 {
             db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Remove(tm);
             int rowiseffected=db.SaveChanges();
             return rowiseffected;
        }
        else
        {
        return 0;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Find` only works for the Primary Key.
Use Linq `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` for other properties.

```
public int saveNewUser(int usr_groupId, int usr_doctypeids)
{
     ts_grp_perm_mapping tm = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.SingleOrDefault(ts => ts.grp_id == usr_groupId);
     if(tm == null)
         throw new Exception($"The grp_id {usr_groupId} was not found");
     db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Remove(tm);
     int rowiseffected=db.SaveChanges();
     return rowiseffected;
}
```

And if possible make your method `async` and use

```
ts_grp_perm_mapping tm = await db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.SingleOrDefaultAsync(ts => ts.grp_id == usr_groupId).ConfigureAwait(false);
//...
int rowiseffected = await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The above method worked for me. Thanks, Also can i know the usage if savechangesasync()?

Comment: If you don't know how async and await work, i suggest you read the MSDN article at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
        public int saveNewUser(int usr_groupId, int usr_doctypeids) 
    { 
      var tm = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Where(a => a.grp_id == usr_groupId); 
      db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Remove(tm); 
      int rowiseffected=db.SaveChanges();
      return rowiseffected;
    }
```

Comment: why should OP try this? Could you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: This won't work, `Where` returns `IQueryable<ts_grp_perm_mapping>` and `Remove` expects `ts_grp_perm_mapping` you need to use `RemoveRange`

Comment: .Find is looking for the primary key. grp_id isn't the primary key, but OP is feeding in the grp_id

Comment: Thanks for everyone whoever helped me.