# Delete row in DataGridView and database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm completely new to databases and EF but I made a database with EF and have a DataGridView control on a windows form that I made by dragging my datasource to my form.  After the user enters their information and hits the save button it succesfully saves their information in the database using this code

```
public partial class bsMainPage : Form
{
    BSDATAContainer db = new BSDATAContainer();
    public bsMainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BSRecords breakfastRecord = new BSRecords();
        breakfastRecord.BS = brkBS.ToString();
        breakfastRecord.Carbs = brkCarb.ToString();
        breakfastRecord.Notes = brkftNoteTxt.Text;
        breakfastRecord.Date = dateTxt.Text;
        BSRecords lunchRecord = new BSRecords();
        lunchRecord.BS = lchBS.ToString();
        lunchRecord.Carbs = lchCarb.ToString();
        lunchRecord.Notes = lnchNoteTxt.Text;
        lunchRecord.Date = dateTxt.Text;
        BSRecords dinnerRecord = new BSRecords();
        dinnerRecord.BS = dnrBS.ToString();
        dinnerRecord.Carbs = dnrCarb.ToString();
        dinnerRecord.Notes = dnnrNoteTxt.Text;
        dinnerRecord.Date = dateTxt.Text;
        db.BSRecords.Add(breakfastRecord);
        db.BSRecords.Add(lunchRecord);
        db.BSRecords.Add(dinnerRecord);
        db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

But it doesn't show up in the database until I restart the program.  When the user selects a row in the DataGridView and hits the delete button which has this code

```
private void deleteRowsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.bSRecordsDataGridView.SelectedRows)
    {
        bSRecordsDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It deletes the data in the DataGridView but doesn't save the changes in my database.  I have followed all the answers I found on here and other sites to delete in the database but nothing will save the deleted changes.  Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: for your new object additions, it sounds like you're not rebinding your grid, off the top of my head, I'm not sure of the syntax (partially why I'm leaving this as a comment).  For the deletion, it looks like you're removing the record from the data grid as opposed to your data source (they're two separate things).  You'll also need to rebind the data after a deletion as well, else you'll end up with the same issue there.  It looks like there's currently (as of time of writing) one answer for this question that tackles the deletion anyways...

Comment: You have options of FirstOrDefault or SingleorDefault to get data [Related answer to Delete row ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172596/how-to-delete-single-row-from-database-using-linq-query-in-mvc-4/35198323#35198323)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it using remove. You will need to get the key/id field so without seeing the grid and assuming it is say in a hidden first column:

```
private void deleteRowsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string delId;
    BSRecords deleteRecord;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.bSRecordsDataGridView.SelectedRows)
    {
        bSRecordsDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);

        // code to remove record from database
        delId = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();  // column that has id field
        deleteRecord = db.BSRecords.First(b => b.Id == delId);    // get the record. will throw exception if not found.
        db.BSRecords.Remove(deleteRecord);

    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    bSRecordsDataGridView.DataBind();   // this will refresh your grid. Do same in save.
}
```

Also note you can rewrite this code:

```
BSRecords breakfastRecord = new BSRecords();
breakfastRecord.BS = brkBS.ToString();
breakfastRecord.Carbs = brkCarb.ToString();
breakfastRecord.Notes = brkftNoteTxt.Text;
breakfastRecord.Date = dateTxt.Text;
```

with an object initializer:

```
BSRecords breakfastRecord = new BSRecords { BS = brkBS.ToString(), 
                                            Carbs = brkCarb.ToString(),
                                            Notes = brkftNoteTxt.Text, 
                                            Date = dateTxt.Text };
```

Comment: Thank you but I got an error here
    b => b.Id == delId
so I had to write
    b.ID == decimal.Parse(delId)
but when I ran it and tried to delete a row I got an 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error at this line
     delId = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Then Cell[0] is probably null then. Show your grid markup or change the [0] to whatever column your key is in.